Run JMeter script in AzureDevOps - Bearer Access Token generation

Automating run and monitor Jmeter API based load tests in Azure DevOps Pipelines

The application to be tested needs to login using clientid, client secret and bearer access token that expires every 24 hours.
The JMeter script is ready and it runs well in GUI mode and in local machine CLI.
The same script is used in Azure DevOps Pipelines with password protection using Azure.
The client id and secret in the script is replaced by variable name which will be substituted with its real values from Azure environment variable manager.
The Bearer access token portion in the script is replaced with this : "Bearer ${AccessToken}"
The Pipeline has JMeter, CLI, Upload Release Artifact.Deployment happens successfully. When i download and the opne the logs, i get the below error:

HTTP request : 400/Bad Request
ReportRequest_viewChart : 401/Unauthorized

In the log, i do get messages like: All thread groups have been started.
After retry, The Bearer access token portion in the script is replaced with this ${__groovy(System.getenv('AccessToken'),)}
Still the same error:'400/Bad Request' and '401/Unauthorized'.
What should I do differently?
Does the problem lie in access token part or somewhere else?
I did try to run this test for other websites where login is not needed. They work well.
Please help

Your __groovy() function syntax is correct and it will return the environment variable value (given it's defined)

So make sure that you properly define your environment variable in your pipeline.
Also I think the Bearer token shouldn't be provided via environment variable, you should rather correlate it (simulate the login flow and extract it from the response using a suitable JMeter Post-Processor)

Thanks for the immediate response..i tried your suggestion
Steps followed

Used the following groovy values and substituted in the jmx file ${__groovy(System.getenv('AccessToken'),)}
Passed the following in the cmd line in azure devops
-------------------------export var1=***
export var2=###
jmeter -n -t testplan.jmx -l Loadtstresult.jtl -e -o LTreport


got this comment - export is not recognized as an internal or external command
what am i doing wrong?

If you're running your script on Windows there is no export command there, the Windows equivalent is set. Cross-platform solution would be using JMeter Properties instead, i.e. run JMeter as jmeter -Jvar1=foo and use __P() function as ${__P(foo,)} to read the value in the script.

Thanks a lot Ivan....your suggestion helped.
